# Google Analytics in Angular and Real Time traffic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-analytics

I've seen a lot of discussion threads recommending to send the **page** parameter to the analytics collector in SPA websites, e.g. in Angular like this:

```
$window.ga('set', 'page', $location.url());
$window.ga('send', 'pageview');
```

But that didn't work for me, I just couldn't see my clicks in the real time overview. After some requests comparing I found out sending **location** parameter works as I expect (dl vs. dh + dp param):

```
$window.ga('set', 'location', window.location.origin + window.location.pathname);
$window.ga('send', 'pageview');
```

The question is - am I missing the point of the real time analytics? Are the Angular routed page clicks (firing analytics collecting on $viewContentLoaded) not supposed to be visible there? Why would be I one of the only ones to be needing the location parameter?

Comment: there are several angular modules available to simplify this. Might want to take a look at those. Also would be simpler to use router events rather than `$viewContentLoaded`  to handle it

Comment: I know about the modules, but it seemed it could be a very simple solution of 5 lines of code. I use the $viewContentLoaded because that guarantees page title to be properly set and displayed in GA, $routeChangeSuccess gives undefined page title.

Comment: Where does title come from? Should be easy enough to use a service to get title or have it defined in routing config

Comment: Thats true, I can use the router event and set $window.ga('set', 'title', 'some title');

Comment: Yes...otherwise it sounds like you would be doing it inside each and every main route controller